# How can I access variables from another class JAVA

Tags: java, oop, object

So i am developing a program to simulate a collection system and the main system takes in items but there are different types of items such as those that require an id check etc... I am using a polymorphic method to access these different classes however is it possible for me to change a variable from the main class based off what occurs in the method that accesses the other class.

EX:

```
itemCollection firstCollect = new itemCollection();
Item test = new AlcoholItem(5.94, false, 3.76. 0.06) // takes in weight, bulk, price, and sinTaxRate.
```

Lets say I have to keep an expected weight of the collection for all non bulk items and have a variable in the itemCollection class called bulk, how can I use the fact that this item isn't bulk. Can I from within the AlcoholItem class method which is Polymorphic can I change itemCollection's bulk variable from the AlcoholItem class?

Comment: You probably want to post more code, best if it is small self-contained representational program code, a [mcve]. This will allow better understanding of your problem.

Comment: If you have a variable in class ItemCollecion called "bulk", then to reference it from another class is must either be declared as public or else the ItemCollection must have a public getter for bulk that returns its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access variables from another class JAVA ?

Generally you want to avoid that and favor methods for that : getters to retrieve values and setters to set values from objects of other classes.

> Can I from within the AlcoholItem class method which is Polymorphic
>   can I change itemCollection's bulk variable from the AlcoholItem
>   class?

Adding a bulk item doesn't mean that all items are bulk. You should give a clear semantic about the `bulk` field in `ItemCollection`.

About updating the weight for no bulk items in the collection, I would do things in the other way since the collection of items depends on the items : when you add an item in the collection, check whether the item is not bulk, if it is not : update the weight of the collection according to.
Generally you want to avoid bidirectional coupling between classes/objects as much as possible.
You should also define a `boolean isBulk()` method in the item class/interface.

In `ItemCollection` class the `add()` could look like:

```
public void add(Item item){
   if (!item.isBulk()){
      weight += item.getWeight();
   }
   else{
       bulk = item.isBulk(); // as discussed check the relevance of this flag.
   }
   // ...
}
```

Comment: `bulk = bulk;` is quite a useless statement.

Comment: @FredK Sure. Not a great confidence into the meaning of this field, I probably botched this part.